# How to start a Spring Batch job as a background thread

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We want to start a job in the background so it doesn't use all resources within the application and can influence the 'normal' tasks of the application. It should start from within the a running Java app and not executed from the command line.

Does anybody know how to start a Spring Batch job as a background task/daemon using Spring scheduling?

Comment: You can use Spring Scheduler(https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) to schedule tasks. As for resource consumption, there's many factors that will affect it. Worse case is just to buy more memory if needed as memory are relative cheap (that is if it is hosted somewhere).

Comment: I know that I can use Spring Scheduler but I am not 100% that the Spring Scheduler actually creates a deamon like thread with a low thread priority. Is there any way to validate this? Also in my specific use case the job should actually run only once and shouldn't be scheduled to repeat itself.

Comment: I can't validate that Spring Scheduler will run with lo thread priority. If it's a job that run only once, it might be easier to write a script for it. You can probably use your Spring application to execute that script based on the condition you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more investigation I found out you can configure a TaskExecuter for a JobLauncher. You can then use a SimpleAsyncTaskExector and configure it as a deamon and set the thread priority.

```
@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher(final JobRepository jobRepository, final TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {

    final SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    return jobLauncher;
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {

    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setDaemon(true);
    taskExecutor.setThreadPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    return taskExecutor;
}
```